# jquery load on scroll function is not working correct

Tags: jquery, function, automation, infinite-scroll

I us the jquery.ias.js by fieg which has a function "onRenderComplete".
You can get this at[github link](https://github.com/webcreate/infinite-ajax-scroll)

I have an articlelist with an the loading of new items works pretty good.
But there is a script part for each of the items which is generating a express-view

```
$("p.ex-[ID]").click(function(){
        $(".express-[ID] .top").delay(500).load("/[Name4URL]/a-[ID]/ .express");
        $(".express-[ID] .bottom-ex .ex-desc").delay(500).load("/[Name4URL]/a-[ID]/ #tab1.tab_content");
        $(".express-container-[ID]").fadeIn(500);

        window.setTimeout(function() {
            MagicZoomPlus.refresh("Zoomer2");
            $(".mz-thumbs a:gt(3)").addClass("nope");
            $(".mz-thumbs a:gt(7)").addClass("nope2");

            $(".image-container .mz-thumbs a:eq(3)").addClass("no-margin-right no-margin-top");
            $(".image-container .mz-thumbs a:eq(7)").addClass("no-margin-right");
            $(".image-container .mz-thumbs a:eq(0)").addClass("no-margin-top");
            $(".image-container .mz-thumbs a:eq(1)").addClass("no-margin-top");
            $(".image-container .mz-thumbs a:eq(2)").addClass("no-margin-top");
        }, 1200); 
    });



    $(".express-container-[ID] .close").click(function(){
        $(".express-[ID] .top").load("/[Name4URL]/a-[ID]/ .clear");
        $(".express-[ID] .bottom-ex .ex-desc").load("/[Name4URL]/a-[ID]/ .clear");
        $(".express-container-[ID]").fadeOut(500);
    });
```

For the none-loaded items, this works fine. But the new loaded items are not firing.
This is the jquery.ias part:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
jQuery.ias({
    container : ".container",
    item: ".item",
    pagination: ".articlePages",
    next: 'a .next',
    loader: '<img src=/layout/cyt/img/ajax-loader.gif"/>',
    triggerPageThreshold: 1,
    history: false,
    onRenderComplete: function(items) {


    }
});
});
```

I have tried to implement the script part into the onRenderComplete function but it does not work and i really do not know how to.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you should use the jquery .on() method http://api.jquery.com/on/. click method doesn't work on dynamically inserted DOM elements. You should do something like this:

```
$("selector-that-contains-p.ex-[ID]").on("click", "p.ex-[ID]", function() {// do the stuff
});
```